# Can I use exceptions as a condition for if statements?

Tags: java

Just a quick question. Is it possible to use an exception as a condition in if statements? I am validating a date format that must be written in "yy/mm/dd". So if the user inputs a date in "mm/dd/yy" or "dd/mm/yy" format, it must show an error message.

Here's my code:

```
String message = null;

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {
        try {

            List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();

            GetAllEmployee get = new GetAllEmployee();
            SrchName getFName = new SrchName();

            String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
            String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String sDate = request.getParameter("sDate");
            String eDate = request.getParameter("eDate");

            String search = request.getParameter("search");

            if (request.getParameter("page") != null)
                page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
            else {
                page = 1;
            }

            startRow = (recordsPerPage * (page - 1) + 1);
            endRow = startRow + 9;

            if (request.getParameter("search") == null) {
                emp = get.list(startRow, endRow);

                noOfRecords = get.getNoOfRecords();
                message = Integer.toString(noOfRecords) + " results";

            } else {

                if (request.getParameter("sDate") != null
                        || request.getParameter("eDate") != null) {

                    if (!Validator.isValidDate(request
                            .getParameter("sDate"))
                            || !Validator.isValidDate(request
                                    .getParameter("eDate"))
                            || !Validator.isValidDate(
                                    request.getParameter("sDate"),
                                    request.getParameter("eDate"))) {
                    } else if (!Validator.isValidDateFormat(request
                            .getParameter("sDate"))
                            || !Validator.isValidDateFormat(request
                                    .getParameter("eDate"))) {
                    }
                }
                if (sDate != null) {
                    request.setAttribute("sDate", "&start=");
                }

                if (eDate != null) {
                    request.setAttribute("eDate", "&end=");
                }

                emp = getFName.srchFName(startRow, endRow, fname, lname,
                        email, sDate, eDate);

                    noOfRecords = getFName.getNoOfRecords();

                        message = "Enter HIRE DATE in valid form";

                    if(noOfRecords == 0){
                        message = "There is no search results for the specified conditions";
                    }else{
                        if(noOfRecords == 1){
                            message = Integer.toString(noOfRecords) + " result";
                        }else{
                            message = Integer.toString(noOfRecords) + " results";
                        }
                    }

                }

            request.setAttribute("fname", fname);
            request.setAttribute("lname", lname);
            request.setAttribute("email", email);
            request.setAttribute("sDate", sDate);
            request.setAttribute("eDate", eDate);
            request.setAttribute("search", search);

            request.setAttribute("emp", emp);

            request.setAttribute("message", message);

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/EmployeeList.jsp").forward(
                    request, response);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot obtain Employees from DB", e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tried to put the exception the catch clause, but it only returns an error suggesting to remove that clause.

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what your specific question is, what you're trying to do, what happens, what you expect to happen.

Comment: If the code block inside the `try` statement does not throw `SQLException` or `ClassNotFoundException`, then your IDE will tell you to remove it.  Why did you put the code in a `try`-`catch` block?

Comment: I suppose you are trying to validate the date string via exception. Please state which line you want to do the check in if statement. But normally we don't use exception to distinguish, there's lots of other ways like regex, helper class etc to validate the input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your code is complaining due to throwing an exception in a catch phrase.

With given description and the code attached, I assume the problem is that "ServletException" is a checked exception meaning that you have to add that exception to your methods declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exception as conditions just if your condition makes an exception, you know that in java each exception has a name, compile and execute your program and notice what is the name of the exception, then copy the name of the exception in the catch statement, the condition should be in the try statement.

if your condition doesn't make exception then you can't use the catch statement.
As I know...